# How to deserialize a json representation of a Python table of objects

Tags: python, json, sqlite, serialization, sqlalchemy

I have a Point Class 
Drawing class, whose member is a list of Point's

I would like to put the Drawing class into an sqlite record with sqlalchemy, and for that I needed to serialized the Point's list.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def encode_Point(obj):

    if isinstance(obj, Point):
        return obj.__dict__

    return obj

class Drawing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_points = []
        self.m_name = "Foo"
```

At the encoding time:

```
pointsJsonDump = dumps(drawing.m_points, default=encode_Point)
i.execute(name='Bar', points=pointsJsonDump)
```

What the 'dumps' function gives is for example:

```
[{"y": 71, "x": 373}, {"y": 104, "x": 342}, {"y": 183, "x": 338}, {"y": 200, "x": 433}, {"y": 140, "x": 504}]
```

I then store this string into a table of sqlite with sqlalchemy.

Now I would like to be able to retrieve this record into a Python object again:
So I stared like this:

```
s = self.m_drawingsTable.select()
rs = s.execute()

for row in rs:
    d = Drawing()
    # Put the record into a Python object
    # Here i put each field into a member of an object
    # Ex: d.name = row.name
```

but how can I rebuild a Point[] from the json object?

Comment: Why serialise *at all*? Using a separate table and foreign key relationships would let you actually *query for membership* instead.

Comment: If you are using SQLAlchemy, then creating such relationships is quite easy, provided you [model the data properly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html).

Comment: Thanx Martijn for your answer. Foreign key relationships is a good idea.
 However I would need a serialised version of these list of points, because of special requirements in my project. Isn't there an easy way to deserialize this json?

Comment: That's a separate problem; most people put extra methods on their models to facilitate reflecting data as a Python structure that can be JSON-serialized.